# C#, How to split a byte array by delimiter?

Tags: c#, split, arrays, delimiter

I have a byte array that contains a collection of 2 byte hexadecimal numbers separated by ','. How could it be split by ',' and then the numbers be converted to integers?

The byte array contains values in ascii format.

edit:
Example

My valid character range is 0 to 9 ,A to F and comma
so my stream should look like

70, 67, 65, 57, 44, 55, 68, 66, 53, 44....

this would be equivalent to hexadecimal

FCA9 and 7DB5

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 6):

If your byte array is truly ASCII encoded (ONE byte per character), then the following would work:

```
int[] ints = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiEncodedBytes).Split(',')
             .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x,16)).ToArray();
```

This will handle mixed case and variable length hex numbers, too.

Comment: Good one! What does this do "Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x,16)).ToArray();"

Comment: Check out the documentation for [Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) and [Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the byte array to string and then use String.Split(',')

Comment: are you suggesting something like this     string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
string [] sarr = str.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int [] intarr = new int[sarr.Length];
    for (int s = 0; s < sarr.Length; s++) {
intarr[s] =  int.Parse(sarr[s], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    }

Comment: The same as jmh_gr but he was 30 sec faster and posted an example hehe.. i typed my answer using my phone. But yes something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, though my C# is a bit rusty...

```
byte[]    input = { 1, 0, 0, 0, ',', 10, 15, ',', 100, 0, 0, 0, ',' };
List<int> output = new List<int>();

int lastIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i ++) {
    if (input[i] == ',')
    {
         if (i - lastIndex == 4)
         {
             byte[] tmp = { input[i - 4], input[i - 3], input[i - 2], input[i - 1] };
             output.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(tmp, 0));
         }

         lastIndex = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm getting the bytearray from reading the serial port. So I may have irregular input. Would it be possible to split the array first by comma and then check if the length of each is 4

Comment: I edited my question, it is actually 2bytes. and the format is in ascii so each number would take 4 locations in the byte array. My valid range is between 0 to 65535

Comment: @KevinBoyd Alright, check my most recent answer. It works in C for me, and I think my C# conversion was right.

Comment: @richard-j-ross-iii trying it out now!

Comment: @richard-j-ross-iii: Compile error, No overload for method 'ToInt32' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @richard-j-ross-iii: BitConverter.ToInt32(tmp, 0) this line is not giving me the expected results. Instead if I convert that line to 
string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tmp); 
output.Add( int.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)); it works. Any idea why BitConverter isn't working out here?

Comment: @KevinBoyd no clue. Could be endianness, I suppose.